# CMPXCHG8B example using Nasm Assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

Can anyone please, give me a very simple example of how to use the x86 **CMPXCHG8B** instruction with the NASM assembler?

Comment: Sure...   `cmpxchg8b [offset]`

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : sure, but can you think of a reason WHY qword isn't allowed as a size specifier (on this instruction) in NASM? There is only one form - sure, but what would be problematic by being explicit about the size? YASM will happily assemble it. If you put DWORD in _YASM_ it will be kind enough to tell you the size doesn't match. I don't see the reason why _NASM_ doesn't allow it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch needs somebody to report/ask nasm devs (or even produce a patch), unfortunately I'm not one of the devs, I just love to use it.

Comment: It is likely so low priority that it isn't worth changing.

Comment: And the same problem happens with the instruction **CMPXCHG16B**, if I used it with the operand size specifier **oword**, like this: **cmpxchg8b oword [value]**, I get the following error: **error: mismatch in operand sizes**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything should be explained by comments, labels and code structure, just a note to `lock` prefix. While it makes it atomic, it makes it also very slow, as all cores has to synchronize at that point and make sure there's no collision in memory access.

Then again, there's usually no sane reason to use `cmpxchg`-like instructions without `lock`, as atomic synchronization of parallel processes is the only usage where it does outperform many other solutions.

For true simple non-atomic "exchange" of memory content a classic set of `mov` instructions will very likely outperform any `xchg`, especially if you plan the swapping ahead and read/write all values with appropriate delays to not choke on memory bandwidth access.

If you expected some tutorial on parallel programming syncing here, then just google for some book/etc, that's not "one answer" topic, but more like "one book" topic.

```lisp
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                 ;tell linker entry point

    ; fail example (memory contains different than expected value)

    ; edx:eax = old value (to compare with memory)
    mov eax,'BAD '
    mov edx,'val.'
    ; ecx:ebx = new value to set
    mov ebx,'NEW '
    mov ecx,`val\n`
    ; CMPXCHG8B should fail, old value is different
    lock cmpxchg8b [value]  ; "lock" makes it atomic for multi-core
    ; here edx:eax == `OLD val\n` (the unexpected content of [value])

    call displayValue

    ; pass example (memory value as expected)

    ; edx:eax = old value (to compare with memory)
    mov eax,'OLD '
    mov edx,`val\n`
    ; ecx:ebx = new value to set
    mov ebx,'NEW '
    mov ecx,`val\n`
    ; CMPXCHG8B should pass, setting up new value
    lock cmpxchg8b [value]  ; "lock" makes it atomic for multi-core

    call displayValue

    ;system call number (sys_exit)
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

displayValue:
    mov edx, 8      ;message length
    mov ecx, value  ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    ret

section .data

value  db   `OLD val\n`     ; 8 bytes long memory
```

To build and run, save it as some "cmpxchg8b.asm":

```
nasm -f elf32 cmpxchg8b.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o cmpxchg8b cmpxchg8b.o
./cmpxchg8b
```

Expected output (on linux box, of course):

```
$ ./cmpxchg8bdemo
OLD val                                                                  
NEW val
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what intrigues me though, is that, unlike other instructions in NASM, the operand of cmpxchg8b didn't use dword or qword before [value], which is unusual.

Comment: @MaykelJakson: I don't get it, did you check Intel reference guide for the definition of instruction? It has only "m64" variant (actually it's encoded in the name of instruction, that "8B" at its end means "8 bytes wide argument"). So there's no need to specify the argument size, it is fixed by the definition. Now I would expect the nasm to silently eat `cmpxchg8b qword [value]`, but actually it fails to compile, weird. Ok, this is puzzling me too, I would expect it to silently match `qword` specifier against `qword` definition and ignore it (and fail on other size specifiers of course).

Comment: that's what I'm talking about, **cmpxchg8b qword [value]** didn't work for me, and I always use the size specifier in NASM. So my code didn't compile, this is why I asked for help.

Comment: @MaykelJakson when you say it didn't work for you -in what way didn't it work? (it failed to compile/assemble, or the code ran but not the way you expected?

Comment: @MichaelPetch actually it didn't compile at all. I've got the following error: **error: mismatch in operand sizes**

Comment: @MaykelJakson : your question lacks any code. Can you edit your question with a complete code example that demonstrates the error you are getting?

Comment: @MaykelJakson would I knew that, I wouldn't bother with such answer in the first place and simply told you to remove `qword`.

Comment: @Ped7g : I'd point out that I consider it a bug that _NASM_ doesn't support qword there. _YASM_ doesn't complain.

Comment: @Ped7g actually a full example might be helpful for other people in the future too.